# C program for first seven terms of logarithmic series

Tags: c

The natural logarithm can be approximated by the following series.
[image]

If x is input through the keyboard, write a program to calculate the
 sum of first seven terms of this series.
 I wrote the program as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()

{

    float x, i, sum, log_sum;
    printf("Enter the value of x : ");
    scanf("%f",&x);
    sum=0;
    for (i=2; i<=7; i++)
    {
         sum=sum+((1/2)*pow(((x-1)/x), i));
    }
    log_sum=((x-1)/x)+sum;
    printf("\nSum of log series is %f\n",log_sum);

    return 0;
}
```

**The output is not matching with calculator answer. What maybe wrong here?**

Comment: integer division... `1/2` is zero; `7/3` is two; try `1.0/2`, `7/3.0` or `(double)1/2`, `(double)7/(double)3`

Comment: I guess, `.5` is good enough :)

Comment: Always (yes, always) prefer `double` when dealing with floating-point values.

Comment: To better understand this, break up the formula in smaller parts and print the value of each part.

Comment: suggestion (premature optimization): move `(x-1)/x` to outside the loop

Comment: Even with the integer division bugs fixed, your series is incorrect.  The coefficients aren't all 1/2.  Check your math.

Comment: @TomKarzes 1/2 is not in the first term, that's why i kept that outside the for loop. Is there anything else i'm missing

Comment: @pmg please show me how to put that outside the loop so that code can be less and working.

Comment: the correct *n*th term is `1.0/n * ((x - 1) / x) ^ n`

Comment: `double y = (x - 1) / x; for (...) { sum = ... * pow(y, i); }`

Comment: @AshfiRahman Yes, there is.  Your math is wrong.  I think pmg's comment shows the correct series.  The series you posted can trivially be reduced to a closed form, which obviously doesn't exist for log so it cannot be right.

Answer (score 1):

In the `for` loop you multiply everything by `(1/2)`, given `1` and `2` are integers, the answer will be `0`. Try multiplying by `0.5` instead, does that solve the problem?

Comment: Even with this fix, it still won't work.  The series shown in OP's post is incorrect.

Comment: @Ashfi, where did you get the series from?

Comment: @FraserDavies This is in the book "Let us C" by Yashavant Kanetkar. Chapter 6 ques no. [c] (h)

Comment: If that's the series that appears in the book, then the book is wrong.  The series is incorrect.  Try to find a more competent book.

Comment: @TomKarzes Maybe they printed it wrong in the book but I have found this book good for learning C. So, accordingly I will change the program with correct series. Thanks !!!